# How to disable visual "dots" in Visual Studio Editor

Tags: visual-studio

How can I can disable the "dots" for spaces in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Untick *Edit* -> *Advanced* -> *View White Space*.

.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of this option. Either it isn't default, or I turned it off first thing without thinking too much about it.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: It's off by default. You can put it on by doing Ctrl-R Ctrl-W, which is I guess what the OP has done unintentionally. You can turn it off that way too.

Comment: In the new versions of VS Code, you'll find the option in View > Render Whitespace

Comment: In my version of VS 2019 I can only get rid of the Tab arrows using the recipes suggested, but the 'dots' remain unmoved. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 71):

You've enabled "Show spaces". Turn them off with Ctrl+R Ctrl+W, or Edit > Advanced > View Spaces

Answer (score 50):

For Visual Studio 2010 or later:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 21):

Keyboard shortcut : Ctrl R + Ctrl W

Comment: Would it be possible for you to expand upon your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Great answer, but the same answer was made 4 years ago.

Comment: still working VS 2019

Answer (score 8):

in VS Version: 1.39.2 - `2019` in the menu `view -> Render Whitespace`

Answer (score 2):

in vs2022,it was `tools->Text Editor->General->Display->View whitespace`

[image]